# Minecraft SelectedItem: help with block data tags?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically, I need to make a testifier commands that checks for players to hold Blue or Red wool in the hand. To do this I've tried the following:

```
/testfor @a[team=Blue] {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:wool}}
```

(it says that the UUID is in invalid format, but the team specification is not necessary so I removed it)

`/testfor @a {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:wool}`

(It seems it only works with white wool)

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:wool 14}
```

Still not working and

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:wool,Data:14}}
```

But still not recognizing it as red wool... I just can't understand how and where I put the block variation Data...

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason you're using `testfor` instead of a scoreboard objective?  The utility of `testfor` is incredibly limited, and only gains a marginal amount of usefulness in the 1.9 snapshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last attempt was close, but the tag that stores an item's data value is called `Damage`, and is a short (needs an "s" suffix when testing) rather than integer. Your command should look like this:

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:wool,Damage:14s}}
```

The Minecraft wiki has [a good page on NBT data](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format), which is a lot easier than just trying to guess the tags.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Even if "damage" doesn't make much sense, it's misleading.

Comment: Its damage because meatadata is meant to be used as durability aka. damage.

Comment: @Lionitow The metadata is often known as the "damage value", as it was originally made to store the damage of tools. Some tags a pretty arbitrary and inconsistent though, which is why I recommend against trying to guess them.